# Why one of applications thinks that JAVA_HOME is set to openjdk 9 directory? [Not actual anymore]

Tags: java, environment-variables, openjdk

The application (Cocos2d-x) tells that

> JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64

My `/etc/environment` contains this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
```

Content of `~./bashrc`:

```
# Add environment variable ANT_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export ANT_ROOT="/usr/share/ant/bin"
export PATH=$ANT_ROOT:$PATH
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
```

Output of `whereis java`:

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Output of `which java`:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Output of `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode
```

`ls /usr/lib/jvm` gives this:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

JDK itself works: I can compile Java programs and Android Studio's (non-cocos).

Comment: Run `update-alternatives --list java` and post the result

Comment: update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Comment: Please add ant additional info to your post, please check your cocos configuration perhaps your missing a configuration.

Comment: @George Udosen I already managed to install Java 9 properly or almost properly, there another problems now. I think this question is not actual for me anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. This line `export JAVA_HOME` should not be in `/etc/emvironment`, then make `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` this `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"`, and
2. This `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"` in `~/.bashrc` should be replace with these lines:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same.

Comment: Did you do `source ~/.bashrc` after updating `.bashrc` file?

Comment: Yes, I did. And the same to /etc/environment.

Comment: Hell no, man. After that edit I couldn't login. I removed JAVA_HOME and export lines from /etc/environment using liveCD and logged in then.

Comment: I never said you should put `export` lines in `/etc/environment` sorry if you miss understood me. You edited two file and the second step was meant for the `~/bashrc` file.

Comment: ok, but still the same (cocos looks for jdk 9).

Comment: Then install java-9 as you have java-8!